# How to identify specific request came at HTTP Interceptor using Angular 5?

Tags: angular, observable, interceptor

I'm using HTTPInterceptor feature in Angular 5.
It is working as expected while cloning http-request and sending to server(back-end server).
I am showing and hiding application loader from HTTPInterceptor only and this also working fine but i have used polling on one GET request, which fetches data from back-end server in every 5 seconds which makes users irritating. 
So, Is there any way to check specific request in HTTPInterceptor? and also do not allow to show/hide loader on that request.

Following is the current code snippet of intercept function:

```js
  intercept (req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.loadingIndicatorService.showLoader();
    this.customAuthorizationHeader();
    const apiRequest = req.clone({headers:this.headers});
    return next.handle(apiRequest).do
    ((response) => {
        if (response instanceof HttpResponse) {
          this.loadingIndicatorService.hideLoader();
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        this.loadingIndicatorService.hideLoader();
      });
  };
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at what the `HttpRequest` `req` parameter has in it? Maybe there is something there that will help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check the if the `req.url` is equal to the path you want to exclude like below:

```
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // put this before your current code
    if (req.url.indexOf('/* the api path you want to exclude*/') === -1) {
      return next.handle(req);
    }
    // do your stuff here.
    return next.handle(req);
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add a condition based on your `req.url` like this:

```
intercept (req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (!req.url.includes('/some/url-to-be-escaped') {
        // Do nothing
        return next.handle(req);
    }

    this.loadingIndicatorService.showLoader();
    this.customAuthorizationHeader();
    const apiRequest = req.clone({headers:this.headers});
    // The rest of your stuff

    return next.handle(req);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: this is a good solution but just want to add that 'includes" is not working on IE 11. so you might want to use "some"

Answer (score 4):

We can do in above ways like check for URL in interceptor itself,but later if we modify the URL like login to sign in,and signup to join or so.This way of implementation will cause side effect.Or overload the interceptor if we have multiple type of logins/un-authenticated pages.

So i suggest We can use an user defined "InterceptorSkipHeader" from login/signup kind of services

```
unAuthenticatedAPI(someUrl){
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set(InterceptorSkipHeader, '');
    this.httpClient.get<ResponseType>(someUrl, { headers });
}
```

And in interceptor you can just check for request with these header and exclude authenticantion

```
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {    
       if (!req.headers.has(InterceptorSkipHeader)) {
         // set token here.
         const apiRequest = req.clone({headers:this.headers})
       }    
       return next.handle(req);
    }
```